# How to play .mov file using Minim Audio Library

Tags: java, minim

I am trying to play .mov (Quick Time audio) file on MAC and Windows using Minim Audio Library on JAVA platform but it gives following error.

Is there any way to play .mov file using java?

please advice.

Thanks in advance..

```
==== JavaSound Minim Error ====
==== Unsupported Audio File: not a MPEG stream:null

Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ddf.minim.javasound.JSMinim.getAudioRecordingStream(JSMinim.java:201)
    at ddf.minim.Minim.loadFile(Minim.java:357)
    at ddf.minim.Minim.loadFile(Minim.java:341)
    at ddf.minim.Minims.setup(Minims.java:23)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:1402)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:1327)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```